# bam error when adding random effect: data must be a data.frame

Tags: random, mgcv

I have a dataframe with 365814 observations that I want to use for fitting a GAMM with mgcv. 
The following code works:

```
Speed_model_test <- bam(mean_dist~ habitat_type2 +
                          s(Forest_density, bs="cr") +
                          s(Ruggedness, bs="cr") +
                          Hunting_in_season + 
                          Winter_enclosure_yes_no +
                          sex,
                          data = red_deer_15_min2,
                          link = gaussian(type="log"))
```

However, as soon as I add a random effect for the different individuals in the dataset, I get an error when fitting the model with the same dataframe:

```
Speed_model_test <- bam(mean_dist~ habitat_type2 +
                          s(Forest_density, bs="cr") + 
                          s(Ruggedness, bs="cr") +
                          Hunting_in_season + 
                          Winter_enclosure_yes_no +
                          sex + 
                          s(individual.local.identifier, bs="re"),  
                        data = red_deer_15_min2, 
                        link = gaussian(type="log"))
```

> ```
> Error in model.matrix.formula(form, data) : data must be a data.frame
> ```

dput of a subset of 20 rows of the data frame;

```
structure(list(individual.local.identifier = structure(c(1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 
2L, 2L, 2L, 2L), .Label = c("287", "288"), class = "factor"), 
sex = structure(c(2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 
1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L), .Label = c("f", 
"m"), class = "factor"), Winter_enclosure_yes_no = structure(c(2L, 
2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 
1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L), .Label = c("Enclosure", "Not_in_enclosure"
), class = "factor"), habitat_type2 = structure(c(2L, 2L, 
2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 
1L, 2L, 1L, 1L), .Label = c("Forest broadleaved", "Forest mixed"
), class = "factor"), Forest_density = c(89, 89, 89, 85, 
89, 78, 89, 78, 78, 85, 82, 88, 92, 92, 84, 79, 81, 82, 78, 
91, 91), Elevation = c(812.71819639231, 812.71819639231, 
812.71819639231, 814.688653270534, 812.71819639231, 810.163842873485, 
812.71819639231, 810.863673487378, 810.863673487378, 819.792779240948, 
875.486756577389, 875.486756577389, 871.090551232063, 870.898053814855, 
867.046446166005, 884.955026288904, 892.296706081018, 891.967052125287, 
894.643926600538, 891.967052125287, 891.967052125287), Ruggedness = c(1.70343459848473, 
1.70343459848473, 1.70343459848473, 1.55689594664619, 1.70343459848473, 
1.82170429946155, 1.70343459848473, 2.83758431946717, 2.83758431946717, 
3.09308072656422, 3.5744549073835, 3.5744549073835, 3.63864413714904, 
3.42917788317389, 3.68377637029529, 3.30551491495578, 2.60185283715349, 
2.77726377967515, 2.53177892113446, 2.77726377967515, 2.77726377967515
), Hunting_in_season = structure(c(1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 
1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L
), .Label = c("no", "yes"), class = "factor"), Day_of_year = c(67, 
67, 67, 67, 67, 67, 67, 67, 67, 67, 19, 19, 19, 19, 19, 19, 
19, 19, 19, 19, 19), mean_dist = c(11.5347165418407, 6.54004030266076, 
13.286684066724, 21.4957340806599, 32.7032985028738, 39.4752350759861, 
141.139924385665, 123.388962245111, 23.9520420806201, 49.7366465519833, 
12.221956345304, 29.4937937417243, 23.1460769378941, 13.9594085803245, 
69.5344965200506, 109.013360897755, 69.5396750161732, 31.5522698537152, 
24.0577391677004, 15.2614245150277, 17.847702176831)), row.names = c(2L, 
3L, 4L, 5L, 6L, 7L, 8L, 9L, 10L, 11L, 3145L, 3146L, 3147L, 3148L, 
3149L, 3150L, 3151L, 3152L, 3153L, 3154L, 3155L), class = "data.frame")
```

What could cause this error and how can it be solved?

Thanks a lot in advance!

Comment: is `individual.local.identifier` a factor in the data frame?

Comment: Thank you for the answer!                                                                            Yes, it is the first column of the data frame. It is  a factor with 152 levels.

Comment: Do you get a different or any error when switching to `gam()`, just to try?

Comment: Yes, I am getting the same error when using gam instead of bam:                            Error in model.matrix.formula(form, data) : data must be a data.frame

Answer (score 0):

I had the same issue and found out that there is some (undocumented) incompatibility with the package `agricolae`. Once I removed `agricolae` the issue with `mgcv::gam` and 're' was gone.